# finding the coefficient of ${t}^{20}$ in the expansion of ${({t}^{3}-3{t}^{2}+7t+1)}^{11}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, problem-solving, multinomial-theorem

I saw a question in my textbook.I tried to solve it using multinomial theorem.However,i stuck in somewhere.

The question is: find the coefficient of ${t}^{20}$ in  the expansion of ${({t}^{3}-3{t}^{2}+7t+1)}^{11}$

My solution is: A general term of the expansion has the form $C(11;b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)$ ${({t}^{3})}^{b_1}$${({-3t}^{2})}^{b_2}$${({7t})}^{b_3}$${(1)}^{b_4}$

In order to have a coefficient of ${t}^{20}$, we must have $b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4=11$ and $3b_1+2b_2+b_3=20$

I could not move foward in here ,because i could not reach the values of $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$. I obtained just equations like $b_3=20-2b_2-3b_1$ and $b_4=2b_1+b_2-9$.

Can you help me for the rest ? Thank you for your helps..

Comment: Why not **dispense** with any attempt at elegance and simply manually enumerate all satisfying *ordered quadruplets* of $(b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4).$

Comment: @user2661923 when i dispense them, i could not reach the solution which is given the textbook.By the way the answer is  -7643472342

Comment: I am not sure if you can simply do it analytically. But with a symbolic manipolation program like Mathematica you find the answer pretty quickly and it is -7643472342

Comment: This cannot be a closed form. You will not get unique values of $b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4$. You have already written $b_3, b_4$ in terms of $b_1, b_2$ where $ 20 \le 2b_1 + b_2 \ge 9$. From here on, it is sum of all of those coefficients.

Comment: "when I dispense them..." Very good point.  Then, simply edit your query to show your work, using mathJax if needed to insert a table into your query.  Then mathSE reviewers will either verify that you are right and the stated answer is wrong, or they will indicate where you have made a mistake.  If needed, the starting point for mathJax is https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.  mathJax can be used to (for example) display a chart, although it will take some effort for you to dig out the appropriate mathJax commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerating the tuples is not very hard. As we see $b_j$s are non negative and $b_1\leq6$, so we pick successive legal values of $b_1$, which will limit the upper value of $b_2$: for example if we pick $b_1=3$, we get $2b_2+b_3=11$, which limits the upper value value of $b_2$ at $5$. We then pick successive values of $b_2$ and so on. $b_4$ is just the residue needed to sum up to $11$. We truncate wherever the sum of $b_1, b_2, b_3$ exceeds $11$.
So here's a table where I list out the tuples in this order.

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c|c|c}
    b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & \frac{11!}{b_1!b_2!b_3!b_4!} & (-3)^{b_2}7^{b_3}\\
    6 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 2310 & -3\\
    6 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 4620 & 49\\
    \hline
    5 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 27720 & 63\\
    5 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 27720 & -1029\\
    5 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 2772 & 16807\\
    \hline
    4 & 4 & 0 & 3 & 11550 & 81\\
    4 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 69300 & -1323\\
    4 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 34650 & 21609\\
    4 & 1 & 6 & 0 & 2310 & -352947\\
    \hline
    3 & 5 & 1 & 2 & 27720 & -1701\\
    3 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 46200 & 27783\\
    3 & 3 & 5 & 0 & 9240 & -453789\\
    \hline
    2 & 7 & 0 & 2 & 1980 & -2187\\
    2 & 6 & 2 & 1 & 13860 & 35721\\
    2 & 5 & 4 & 0 & 6930 & -583443\\
    \hline
    1 & 8 & 1 & 1 & 990 & 45927\\
    1 & 7 & 3 & 0 & 1320 & -750141\\
    \hline
    0 & 10 & 0 & 1 & 11 & 59049\\
    0 & 9 & 2 & 0 & 55 & -964467\\
\end{array}\right]$$

The grunt part is of course computing the multinomial coefficient and the product of powers. But once you do a sum of their pairwise products you get:

Coefficient of $t^{20}$ = $-7643472342$

I verified the answer programmatically and at [this polynomial expansion calculator](http://www.mathportal.org/calculators/polynomials-solvers/polynomials-expanding-calculator.php?val1=(x%5E3-3x%5E2plus7xplus1)%5E11&val2=%7B%5Cleft(%7Bx%7D%5E%7B3%7D-3%7Bx%7D%5E%7B2%7Dplus7xplus1%5Cright)%7D%5E%7B11%7D)

Answer (score 0):

From $3b_1+2b_2+b_3=20$ follows equal parity of $b_1$ and $b_3.$
Then $b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4=11$ says that $b_2$ and $b_4$ have opposite parity.
Shortly: three of the coefficients are odd and one is even, or vice versa.

Now, I suggest to create a table and find systematically all quadruples, e.g. $(0,10,0,1),(0,9,2,0)...$ They are not so many.

[image]

Comment: Then, which one is the correct quadruples?

Comment: should i try all of them until reaching the correct solution?

Comment: @martinscott you were already on the right track. Find coefficient of all possible combinations (along with sign) and add them up.

Comment: Both, and also (2,7,0,2) etc. I started with $b_1=0, b_3=0,$ then the  equation $3b_1+2b_2+b_3=20$ gives $b_2$ and the first equation gives $b_4.$ With the constraint $b_1\leq 6$ it is quite quickly finished. All those quadruples satisfy.